Laravel page blank on including js file in blade
I am trying to output page numbers on print so I am including paged.polyfill.js & interface.css files in my laravel blade file but my page becomes blank and loads content only for a split second on refresh.
code of blade file
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('css')
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/interface.css">
@endsection

@section('content')
...
@endsection

@section('script')
  <script src="/js/paged.polyfill.js"></script>
@endsection

I have tried checking for console errors, syntax but of no help.
I have tried following the paged.js documentation and matched the corresponding js and css file versions too.
I also checked if those files load in my Network tab and they display correctly.
I am using firefox browser and laravel v10.
What am I missing ?

Show the blade template where you loaded paged.polyfill.js & interface.css.Check the path correctly.

@Subha I have included the code and checked thoroughly for syntax, looks correct to me

Do you yield those sections in your parent view?

@brombeer yes ..

@shubhamsingh Are you sure that your JS & CSS files are in public folder.

@Subha Yes, both files are in public folder in js & css folders respectively. Also checked for latest versions of both ..

Try this php artisan view:clear & php artisan optimize:clear,

@shubhamsingh Also try this href="asset('css/interface.css')" for both CSS & JS file

@Subha both didn't work :( but thanks for putting in the time to respond !!

I am sorry to say but I skipped one thing. it should be within double {{ }} href="{{asset('css/interface.css') }}.

No worries, I tried that .. one thing to note is that when I comment the script part of code, it's working.

I am trying to include paged.js script and css files from the following link
https://pagedjs.org/documentation/2-getting-started-with-paged.js/#using-paged.js-as-a-polyfill-in-web-browsers
